# Changing name of Primary Key

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a primary key `AuthorCode` and this is referenced by 2 other tables. If I open this table in Design View and change the name of the column to `ID` or something other than that, will it affect / drop the foreign key constraints, or will it update those constraints and I will be able to use this?

I want to change the names of few columns which happen to be primary keys as well because they are hard to remember while coding. That's why I want to make sure if this is critical or it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can rename the column using sp_rename:

```
EXEC sp_rename '[Schema].[Table].[OldColumn]', 'NewColumn', 'COLUMN';
```

you can rename the constraint by :

```
EXEC sp_rename '[Schema].[Table].[OldConstraint]', 'NewConstraint'
```

MS Docs are here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Renaming a column will not affect it's constraints if you do it using `sp_rename`. To change the column name, you can use this :

```
EXEC sp_rename 'SchemaName.TableName.OldColumnName', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN';
```